# Excel returns TRUE on comparison of two columns. However one cell contains value 0 and other cell is empty

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I compare excel sheet data. If 1st sheet contains '0' and 2nd sheet is empty. Currently, excel return TRUE, which is wrong. I do comparisons like below. Is there any way to return false when value doesn't match or anyone cell is empty.

```
='Sheet1'!A34='Sheet2'!A34
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of workarounds for this.

Use Exact:

```
=EXACT('Sheet1'!A34,'Sheet2'!A34)
```

Force literal strings:

```
='Sheet1'!A34&""='Sheet2'!A34&""
```

[image]